# How to prove consistency of a non constant partial effect

Tags: polynomial, consistency, marginal-effect

Suppose a data generating process behaves according to the following hypotheses, where for simplicity $x$ is a scalar random variable that enters into the model linearly and through a quadratic term:

1. $y=m(x)+e$
2. $m(x)\equiv \beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2$
3. Weak exogeneity: $E[\mathbf{x'}e]=0$, where $\mathbf{x}=(x, x^2)$
4. $E[e]=0$ (since the intercept is included)

I am interested in finding a consistent estimator for $g(x)\equiv \frac{d}{dx}
m(x)=\beta_1+2\beta_2x$ and in finding the limiting distribution of $\sqrt{N}(\hat{g}(x)-g(x))$.

To estimate $(\beta_0,\beta_1)$ it is possible to define $z_1\equiv x$ and $z_2\equiv x^2$ so that we can make OLS of $y$ on $\mathbf{z}$ (by additionally assuming no perfect collinearity among variables).
Hence we get: 
$\mathbf{b}=(\mathbf{z'z})^{-1}(\mathbf{z'}y)$.
Then, under random sampling, we can use the Slustsky theorem and the Weak law of large numbers to show the consistency of the estimator $\mathbf{b}$, i.e. that $plim \mathbf{b}=\textbf{$\beta$} $.

An estimator for $g(x)$ is obtained by simply plugging $\mathbf{b}$ into $g(x)$. 
What I would like to know is how to show that the resulting estimator $\hat{g}(x)=b_1+2b_2x$ is consistent, where $b_1$ and $b_2$ are the estimators of the respective betas.

In particular, I am not sure how to deal with the fact that the partial effect $g(x)$ is not constant, being a function of $x$.
Which results can be used? Can $x$ be considered constant when we increase the sample size $N$ to prove consistency?
On a related note, which is the resulting limiting distribution of $\sqrt{N}(\hat{g}(x)-g(x))$?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**
When I write "the partial effect $g(x)$ is not constant" I refer to the fact that $g(x)$ is a function of the specific value taken by $x$.
In an ordinary regression without polynomial terms this does not happen, as the marginal effects are just the betas in the model (if in this example we had a linear DGP, then $g(x)\equiv \frac{d}{dx}
m(x)=\beta_1$.

Comment: As a matter of terminology, assumption (3) implies $x$ is a random variable. Therefore $g(x)$ is a random variable, too. One would not ordinarily refer to it as something that can be "estimated." In fact, it's not entirely clear what you mean by this expression: does "$x_1$" refer to (a) one value of $x_1$ for one of your observations; (b) the vector of values for all such observations; or (c) an independent random variable with the same distribution as the random variable $x_1$ in the model? In cases (a) and (b) $g(x)$ is something that could be estimated but in (c) it would be *predicted.*

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the question. Here $x$ is a scalar random variable. I am afraid I don't see your point about prediction here. Here the focus is on estimation: any estimator can be seen as a random variable with a specific distribution and moments. In fact, the final goal is precisely to define the limiting distribution of the estimator itself (after having proven its consistency).

Comment: The quality of an estimator (such as its bias) is evaluated with respect to a *fixed quantity* it is estimating. Your $g$ does not estimate a fixed quantity; it therefore is not an estimator in the conventional (technical) sense. Instead it *predicts* the slope of the regression at the random abscissa $x$.  The distinction between an estimator and predictor is of more than conceptual or terminological importance: understanding the place of your problem within the statistical literature helps you explain it to others and helps you find solutions that others have developed and studied.

Comment: As an example, $\beta_1+\beta_2 \mathbb{E}X$ is a combination of unknown, but fixed, parameters that you perhaps could be interested in estimating consistently.

Comment: I do agree with the fact that what we want to estimate must be constant. In fact we should fix $x$ at some value (usually its average) and then evaluate consistency. This is probably the answer to my initial question: if we fix $x$ to some arbitrary value, say the sample mean, then $\hat{g(x)}$ is an estimator and it is trivially consistent as the plim of a constant is the constant itlsef and the OLS estimators are consistent.